# Google API Client returning 404 not fund

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-custom-search

I am trying to get the best searches from google, using keyword, and GoogleAPI, but It is always returning "`System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'`"

Am I doing anything wrong, or is it that GoogleAPI is outdated? Last time I checked and downloaded the .dll file was from 2010...

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.CustomSearchAPI.v1;

//Ignore most using statements, It was imported from my previous code.

namespace TYZDsag
{
   
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new Google.API.Search.GwebSearchClient("https://www.google.com/");
            var results = client.Search("uhuhuh", 12);
            foreach (var webResult in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", webResult.Title, webResult.Url, webResult.Content);
                //listBox1.Items.Add(webResult.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2010?! Google has built, released to beta, and subsequently cancelled entire empires in that time! :)

Comment: [Google's .NET Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) sample code looks nothing like yours. I suspect they've completely rewritten the API, and your library is no longer supported.

Comment: Ouhh, But can you do direct search from console app? to chrome. I really need this to work :'(

Comment: Possibly, but you'll need to sign up for an account and get an API key. There will also be limits to the number of requests you can submit on the free tier; if you need more requests, they'll want to charge you for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not  how you initialize a service object using an api key.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.CustomSearchAPI.v1;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace customsearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var service = new CustomSearchAPIService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "XXX",
                ApplicationName = "xyz",

            });

            var result = await service.Cse.List().ExecuteAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

- [Method: cse.list](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list)
- [How to create an api key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=me_PAqPpzP0)